# How to convert from Array{Float64,2} to Array{Array{Float64,1},1} in Julia

Tags: julia

So, I have been working with a dataset (of my own creation) which was name as `mydata` and it was a `10000-element Array{Array{Float64,1},1}:`. The thing is that I stored it into my computer by using `writedlm("mydata",mydata)` and now, when I read it using `readdlm("mydata",mydata)`, I recover a matrix of type `Array{Float64,2}:`.

The question is:

- Is there an easy way to read the data as a `10000-element Array{Array{Float64,1},1}:`, or, at least, transform my recovered
  matrix to a `Array{Array{Float64,1},1}:` type?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get a vector of vectors, you can write

```
collect(eachcol(a))
```

Edit: In order to get an ordinary `Array{Array{Float64,1},1}`, you can use

```
collect.(eachcol(a))
```

Answer (score 3):

You can drop the dimension using `[:]` operator:

```
julia> a=rand(2,3)
2×3 Array{Float64,2}:
 0.896784  0.653296  0.939789
 0.113942  0.178925  0.470658


julia> @view a[:]
6-element view(::Array{Float64,1}, :) with eltype Float64:
 0.8967838440135203
 0.1139418024781611
 0.6532956345656487
 0.17892503362478984
 0.9397886609896129
 0.4706578162765451
```

The advantage of the above code is that no data is copied so this is practically a zero cost.

There is also a `reshape(a,6)` (or more generally, `reshape(a, length(a))`) option which does not copy the data neither (you still get reference to the same memory location).

Finally, note that you might want to use `Array` slicing operator to actually be sure that you are getting only the first columns (again `@view` avoids data copying):

```
julia> @view a[:,1]
2-element view(::Array{Float64,2}, :, 1) with eltype Float64:
 0.8967838440135203
 0.1139418024781611
```

Answer (score 2):

Apart from patterns shown by Przemyslaw, I also often use:

```
julia> a=rand(2,3)
2×3 Array{Float64,2}:
 0.946128  0.902697  0.831427
 0.647748  0.934436  0.221258

julia> vec(a)
6-element Array{Float64,1}:
 0.9461283739840134
 0.6477484162303082
 0.9026969223072401
 0.934435667665475
 0.8314267308266441
 0.22125755489262455
```

The result of `vec(a)` also shares data with `a` (so there is no copying) and it can be slightly faster to construct and use later than `@view a[:]` as it is a plain vector rather than a view.

Comment: @Przemyslaw : Ok, but that allows me to acces the rows or columns of an array, but doesn't actually convert the ```Array{Float64,2}``` into an ```Array{Array{Float64,1},1}```, right?. I was thinking more like:                                                                      ```Input = rand(10,10);
Irows = size(Input,1);
Output = Array{Array{Float64,1},1}(undef,Irows);
for i=1:Arows
    output[i]=Input[i,:];
end```

Comment: @DFN Ok. ```collect(eachcol(a))``` gives an output that looks like the one I am looking for(same shape: rows of individual vectors), but what is a ```Array{SubArray{Float64,1,Array{Float64,2},Tuple{Base.Slice{Base.OneTo{Int64}},Int64},true},1}:``` type array? Never seen this complex type... is there any way of only having a ```Array{Array{Float64,1},1}```

Comment: it means that the underlying data is shared between the old and the new data structure.

Comment: Ok. Bottom line, is there any way turning that output into a simple ```Array{Array{Float64,1},1}``` ?

Comment: `copy.(eachcol(a))` for instance.